# Center alignment of text with one row

Tags: tables, overleaf

Please I wanna aligne the text of the row, I added **center** element for the text but it's not well centered, do I have to add it somewhere else or there's an other element that help me solve this little issue!

```
    \begin{table}[H]
                \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.21in}p{3.09in}}
    \hline

    \multicolumn{1}{|p{2.21in}}{{ 
\textbf{{ \begin{center} Éléments existants \end{center}  }}} \par } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{4.09in}|}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Cahier de charge détaillé \par    
        \item Données ‘format Flat File'
        \item Données ‘Template et forme rapport à génére'
        \item Structure d’analyse
    \end{itemize}
    } \\
    \hhline{--}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` this will insert additional vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead. If this does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 1):

- since you not provide complete small document (called  *mwe*: minimal working example), from which we can see your document layout. i consider standard article document class.
- it is not clear, how you like that your table would look (how many rows it has, does content in all cells should be vertically and horizontally centered, etc), so the following solution can serve only as starting point ...
- it might be better if for the first column you use `c` column type and for itemize use the `enumitem` package, which enable simple setting for more compact list in the second column (see the second example)

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array}
  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{table}
      \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\bfseries}m{2.21in}|m{3.09in}|}
      \hline
   Éléments existants
      &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Cahier de charge détaillé \par
          \item Données ‘format Flat File'
          \item Données ‘Template et forme rapport à génére'
          \item Structure d’analyse
          \end{itemize}       \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
      \end{table}

      \begin{table}[htb]
      \setlist[itemize]{nosep, topsep=3pt,
                        leftmargin=*,
                        after= \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                      }
      \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|m{3.09in}|}
      \hline
   Éléments existants
      &   \begin{itemize}
          \item Cahier de charge détaillé 
          \item Données ‘format Flat File'
          \item Données ‘Template et forme rapport à génére'
          \item Structure d’analyse
          \end{itemize}       \\
      \hline
  \end{tabular}
      \end{table}
  \end {document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)